# Extract total tax amount from Quote when using TaxJar

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, quote

I have run into an issue with a Magento 1.9 instance that uses TaxJar. I am trying to extract the total tax on the Quote. With a standard Magento 1.9 instance, I can get the total tax as follows

```
$tax = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getTaxAmount()
```

With TaxJar installed, the above statement returns a null.

- Is that expected?
- What is the right way to extract tax from the Quote if the instance has TaxJar installed?

PS: I am a total noob in Magento (Less than 1 month of working on it). For most part, I have found solutions in stackexchange, so thank you all for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the total tax amount based on your example, depending on where you're calling the code. TaxJar only overrides the `collect` method of `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax` [inside this file](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento-extension/blob/master/app/code/community/Taxjar/SalesTax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php#L29) when checkout calculations are enabled.

If you're trying to get the tax amount after the `collect` method is called and you're still getting null, please reach out to TaxJar support and we'll help you figure out the issue once we have more info.